# PDF annotation in flask

Tags: python, flask, annotations

I am referencing https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1545220 to extract highlighted parts from PDF file. I using Flask to upload a pdf file and then perform annotation on the same and further operations. However, I am getting an error which says:

> `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lst' referenced before assignment`

My app.py file in flask looks like below:

```
@app.route('/converted',methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def convert():
    global f1
    fi = request.files['pdf']
    f1 = fi.filename
    fi.save(f1)
    process_file(f1)
    return render_template('converted.html')
```

and script.py as below:

```
def process_file(file):

    def _parse_highlight(annot: fitz.Annot, wordlist: List[Tuple[float, float, float, float, str, int, int, int]]) -> str:
        points = annot.vertices
        pno = ''
        quad_count = int(len(points) / 4)
        sentences = []
        for i in range(quad_count):
            # where the highlighted part is
            r = fitz.Quad(points[i * 4 : i * 4 + 4]).rect

            words = [w for w in wordlist if fitz.Rect(w[:4]).intersects(r)]
            sentences.append(" ".join(w[4] for w in words))

        pno = re.findall(r'^\D*(\d+)', str(annot))
        pno = ",".join(pno)
        sentences.append(pno)
        sentences.append(annot.colors["stroke"])
        return sentences

    def handle_page(page):
        wordlist = page.getText("words")  # list of words on page
        wordlist.sort(key=lambda w: (w[3], w[0]))  # ascending y, then x
        highlights = []
        annot = page.firstAnnot
        while annot:
            if annot.type[0] == 8:
                highlights.append(_parse_highlight(annot, wordlist))
            annot = annot.next
        return highlights


    def main(filepath: str) -> List:
        doc = fitz.open(filepath)

        highlights = []
        for page in doc:
            highlights += (handle_page(page))

        return highlights

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        lst = main(file)               

    #converting page column to integer type
    for x in lst:
        x[-2]=int(x[-2])
```

How can I resolve it? Is there any other to annotate pdf?

Answer (score 1):

`if __name__ == "__main__":` is causing the error, this is an idiom
for determining if a python module was imported or executed directly.
`lst` isn't assigned unless you execute script.py directly.

It's not clear why you're nesting functions under `process_file`, but
`process_file` isn't a module, so this test isn't relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.